# mysql query into querybuilder

Tags: mysql, doctrine, query-builder, symfony-2.8

Is there a way to make a query builder similar to the next one made in Mysql:

```
"SELECT a.* FROM fsa_areas ORDER BY (SELECT count(*) FROM fsa_areas a1 WHERE a1.Responsible = a.Responsible) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I'm trying this:

```
$em->getRepository('FSABundle:FsaAreas')->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('u.name, u.responsible')
        ->where('u.enabled = true')
        ->orderBy('  ','DESC')
        ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

**But I don't know if is possible to do a similar OrderBy in Querybuilder as in Mysql?**

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the query like this:

```
SELECT a.* FROM fsa_areas a
LEFT JOIN fsa_areas a1 ON(a1.responsible = a.responsible)
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY COUNT(a1.id) DESC;
```

And transform it for query builder:

```
$entityManager
        ->getRepository(FsaAreas::class)
        ->createQueryBuilder('a, COUNT(a1) AS HIDDEN cnt')
        ->select('a')
        ->leftJoin(FsaAreas::class, 'a1', Expr\Join::WITH, 'a1.responsible = a.responsible')
        ->groupBy('a')
        ->orderBy('cnt', 'DESC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Comment: Sorry, I get this error Expected known function, got 'COUNT'

Comment: Since DQL order by doesn`t support functions you must use calculated value from select. HIDDEN keyword is used for ignoring the value in requested resultset.